# Jumbled Characters Appearing in WordPress Posts

Tags: wordpress

My Wordpress site is randomly displaying characters such as single and double quotes as jumbled characters. I'm finding this problem especially difficult to diagnose because when we identify the problem on a specific device and/or browser, the post will display correctly on a different device and/or browser. Does anyone know how or why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Without more details from you all we can do is guess. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: This happens most often when content is copy/pasted from word processors. Quotation marks in word processor are rendered differently by the code once they are stored in post_content and then rendered in your templates with `the_content` filter. Content may need to be cleaned up either before it is entered or programatically using some custom code or a plugin.

Comment: We have a number of people contributing via posts, and it was demonstrated to me that the problem occurs when the content is hand-typed. The copy/paste issue was my first guess as well and we've now ruled that out.

Comment: Caberahector... believe me, I understand that more details would be beneficial, but unfortunately I don't really have many more details to divulge. This issue is a bit of a mystery to us. I am at a loss and I was hoping someone here might have run into a similar problem, with some insight as to why it happens and hopefully a solution.